# Append elements form JSON response to multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

Code:

```
var array = Array<Array<String>>()

Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["postType": "live"], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).responseJSON { (_, _, result) in
        switch result {

            case .Success(let data):

                let json = JSON(data)

                for(_,subJSON):(String, JSON) in json["Info"] {

                    let Tag = subJSON["Tag"].string!
                    let Location = subJSON["Location"].string!

                    array.append(Array(count: 4, repeatedValue: concertTag))

                }

            case .Failure(_, let error):

                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

I want to create an array multidimensional. And add JSON variables to it for after pass the array to TableView.

So basically i need "array" to be like:

```
[[Tag1; Location1],[Tag2, Location2], .... ]
```

How can I do this? any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just would have to replace

```
array.append(Array(count: 4, repeatedValue: concertTag))
```

with

```
array.append([Tag, Location])
```

And you would get the data back like this for example:

```
for arr in array {
    print("tag: " + arr[0])
    print("loc: " + arr[1])
}
```

**But I would suggest another approach: using tuples.**

First let's create a type result because it's convenient:

```
typealias TagAndLocation = (tag: String, location: String)
```

Then prepare an empty array of results:

```
var resultTuples = [TagAndLocation]()
```

Fill the array of tuples in the loop:

```
for (_, subJSON) in json {
    let Tag = subJSON["Tag"].string!
    let Location = subJSON["Location"].string!

    let tagloc = (tag: Tag, location: Location)
    resultTuples.append(tagloc)
}
```

Then you can access your data in two ways:

```
for (tag, loc) in resultTuples {
    print("tag: " + tag)
    print("loc: " + loc)
}

for result in resultTuples {
    print("tag: " + result.tag)
    print("loc: " + result.location)
}
```

*Note: your variables names should begin with a lowercase letter. Beginning with uppercase is usually for classes, types, protocols and such.*

Comment: Thank you! And then can I add this array in cellForRowAtIndexPath and use re indexPath.row for the position?

Comment: You're welcome. Wether you choose array of arrays or array of tuples, you will of course be able to retrieve indexed data from it later, it's just that the tuple version will make it easier and safer in my opinion. // As for *how* to do it for your needs in a table is yet another topic and will deserve its own question later if you feel stuck: we shouldn't hijack *this* question which has its own topic. :)

Comment: You are right! I've uploaded a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100734/swift2-0-create-tableview-from-an-array-of-tuples

Comment: Why can't I access the resultTupples outside of the for cycle. If I print it inside I get the array if I print it outside I get empty array.