# Swift2.0 - Create tableView from an array of tuples

Tags: arrays, json, tableview, swift2

I have an array of tuples that is created from a JSON.

```
typealias TagAndLocation = (tag: String, location: String)

var resultTuples = [TagAndLocation]()

for (_, subJSON) in json {
    let Tag = subJSON["Tag"].string!
    let Location = subJSON["Location"].string!

    let tagloc = (tag: Tag, location: Location)
    resultTuples.append(tagloc)
}
```

Then I'll use

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CellConcert")

           //PROBLEM IS HERE. I want the indexPath.row to be the position of the array of tupple
            cell.textLabel?.text = resultTuples.[indexPath.row][]

            return cell

        }
```

Basically i want my tableView to have the content of concerts.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Shoudn't expression to be `resultTuples[indexPath.row].location` or `resultTuples[indexPath.row].tag`?

Comment: I've tried that but I got fatal error: Array index out of range
(lldb)

Comment: You should then verify what value is `indexPath.row` in all cases to check whether it's going out of the size of your array. The index can't be larger than the array itself.

Comment: pepper is correct. If you're getting an index out of range error it means something is wrong with your code. In other news, you should not be using  the UITableViewCell initializer. You should be calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. This is important for performance and memory management.

Comment: But resultTyples is an array of arrays correct? Shouldn't I be able to access values by resultTuples[1]["Location"]?